# How to convert the order of <li> in an unordered list into a JavaScript Array?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have this unordered list which can be arranged by the user:

```
      <ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
          <li id="1" class="ui-state-default">A</li>
          <li id="2" class="ui-state-default">B</li>
          <li id="3" class="ui-state-default">C</li>
          <li id="4" class="ui-state-default">D</li>
          <li id="5" class="ui-state-default">E</li>
      </ul>
```

I wanted to make a Javascript array based on the arrangement for example if the order is ADBEC then the array should be [1, 4, 2, 5, 3]

An ID has been set for each <li> as an individual identifier.

Please note this refers to the orders of list items not the contents. All help appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the order is guaranteed to be from top to bottom, so:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("#sortable1 li").forEach(function(li) {
  console.log(li.id)
})
```

```html
<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
  <li id="1" class="ui-state-default">A</li>
  <li id="2" class="ui-state-default">B</li>
  <li id="3" class="ui-state-default">C</li>
  <li id="4" class="ui-state-default">D</li>
  <li id="5" class="ui-state-default">E</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: it should be noted that `querySelectorAll` returns a **Node List** not an Array

Answer (score 3):

You can use querySelectorAll to loop through each li and push the id to an array.

```js
let sortable1 = document.querySelectorAll("#sortable1 li"),arry = [];

sortable1.forEach((e)=> arry.push(e.id))

console.log(arry)
```

```html
<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
          <li id="2" class="ui-state-default">B</li>
          <li id="1" class="ui-state-default">A</li>
          
          <li id="3" class="ui-state-default">C</li>
          <li id="4" class="ui-state-default">D</li>
          <li id="5" class="ui-state-default">E</li>
      </ul>
```